# Truthy/falsy in Python

Tags: python

```
def truthy(v):
    if issubclass(v.__class__, numbers.Number):
        return bool(int(v))
    if isinstance(v, basestring):
        vl = v.lower()[0]
        if vl == 'y' or vl == 't':
            return True
    return False
```

1. Is there some type/class I missed that can be evaluated by Python as True/False that I missed here?
2. Drawbacks? Better ways?

Comment: What do you plan to use this for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test this right now, but the `isinstance` seems very unpythonic to me. Assuming that your original logic is correct, why not:

```
def truthy(v):
    try:
        return bool(int(v))
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        first = v.lower()[0]
        return (first == 'y') or (first == 't')
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    return False
```

That way, you don't need to worry about missing any types -- if it's convertible to an `int` or if it implements a `lower()` method you'll catch it.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
accepted_truthy_characters = {'y', 't'}

def truthy(value):
    if isinstance(value, basestring):
        return value and value[0].lower() in accepted_truthy_characters
    return bool(value)
```

In Python 3.x, basestring won't work and you'll need `isinstance(value, str)` instead.

One thing you missed is that `value` might be a string, but it might be empty, which would leave you with an IndexError.

Python's `bool()` will check an `int` for you, so I don't think you need to check if it's a Number, convert it with `int()`, and then `bool()`, unless I'm missing something about your use case.

Out of curiosity, why do you need this? Are you checking user input? Won't that always be a string anyway? And in that case, wouldn't it be better to just check a few allowed "positive" strings?

Comment: this is for parsing (INI) config file settings. Sysadmins are used to entire menagerie of truthy/falsy values across different sw, like: unset value (falsy), 'True', 'true', 't', 'y', 'yes', 1, 0..., so they can make errors. e.g. PHP rubbish is notorious for using all kinds of inconsistent truthy/falsy settings.

Comment: `len(value)` → `value`. `&&` → `and`. `value.lower()[0]` → `value[0].lower()`. `bool(value)` → `value`.

Comment: argh and I forgot one more thing: `''[0]` -> `IndexError`

Comment: `'no'` is a string, so it will be handled by the other return statement.

Comment: @Gareth: if I'm writing "truthy/falsy" filter for a range of input types, I'd prefer to return clean boolean types only rather than truthy/falsy values again..

Comment: Ack, I got '&&' in my python code, ew. Been writing too much javascript.

Comment: @GarethRees I used `bool(value)` to ensure that this function would always return a boolean.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But if `value` is ever used in a context that requires a Boolean, Python will automatically convert it. So (unless the OP gives us more details about how this is going to be used) it doesn't seem necessary to do the conversion here.

Comment: I would want the signature of this function to be "returns Boolean" not "returns True or else the original value".

Comment: Is there any point in also checking __nonzero__ for objects and __len__ for sequences, if only to be 'generous in what you accept'?

Comment: @Gareth: long story short: side effects. Sysadmin A puts "yes" in config file. Programmer A thinks "neat I can put 'y' on the admin summary webpage directly". Sysadmin B on another machine puts 1 in the setting or leaves it unset. People *may* use those values in ways other than boolean-type evaluation. Had the use been limited to boolean-type evaluation, you'd be 100% correct. Unfortunately, there's no guarantee other things will not be done on the truthy() output depending on the output type. If only booleans are guaranteed to be output, it eliminates many schroedinger-type classes of bugs.

Comment: @theodox: my goal is to be "strict in what you send out" rather than be "liberal in what you accept". :-)

Comment: @GarethRees: I do realize this sort of goes against spirit of duck typing. However, in this particular context, there's little to be gained by multiple output types and their methods and much to be lost. There's a lot to be gained by objects of different types having `.sum()` or `.append()` methods, and probably not much to be lost. But if output is expected to mean true or false, most of what different types and methods do here I think is introducing potential for bugs that are hard to find.

Comment: No need for 2 returns `if isinstance(v, basestring): v = v and v[0].lower() in 'yt'` (v is either `''`, `True` or `False`) then `return bool(v)`